# Unable to start mysql server version 5.5

Tags: mysql, amazon-linux

I am using Amazon linux and I've installed the mysql-community-server and mysql-community-client using rpm package.

```
rpm -ivh mysql-community-common-5.5.62-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh mysql-community-libs-5.5.62-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh mysql-community-client-5.5.62-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh mysql-community-server-5.5.62-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

mysql version

```
bash-4.2# /usr/bin/mysql --version
/usr/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

However , I am unable to start the mysql server or set a password. mysql.sock file is missing too. I get the below error , when i try to start mysql server.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I followed the same steps to install mysql5.1.39

```
rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.1.39-0.glibc23.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh MySQL-client-5.1.39-0.glibc23.x86_64.rpm
```

After starting the mysql server '/etc/init.d/mysql start' Can't connect to local MySQL server error was resolved.

But for the version mysql 5.5 ,i could not find the mysql file in this
directory /etc/init.d/

I tried start the server as below and  get a different error.

```
bash-4.2# sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld start
181214 19:35:07 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.62) starting as process 135 ...
181214 19:35:07 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

181214 19:35:07 [ERROR] Aborting

181214 19:35:07 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

bash-4.2# sudo systemctl start mysqld
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
bash-4.2#
```

Comment: The file is missing because the server failed to start, not because it's meant to be put there by the installer. Check the log files to hopefully find out what's wrong.

Comment: No i did check that by installing  rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.1.39-0.glibc23.x86_64.rpm in my docker  mysql file was automatically  added  in /etc/init.d

Comment: Sorry, I was commenting your "mysql.sock file is missing too" statement.

Comment: I couldn find any error logs in /var/log/ dir. i tried to cat this file mysqld.log and this was empty.

Comment: I think I've misread the question. Do you mean that the 5.5 packages do not provide the startup script? Is the lack of such script the reason why you can't start the server?

Comment: I am not sure if that could be the reason.

Comment: Well... What happens when you type `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` then? If the script is missing you'd see something like "sudo: /etc/init.d/mysql: command not found".

Comment: yes thats exactly what it says. bash-4.2# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
sudo: /etc/init.d/mysql: command not found

Comment: How about `/etc/init.d/mysqld start` (with an extra "d" for "daemon")?

Comment: bash-4.2# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory